# selenium-webdriver: get browser-content updated after calling webservice to send new data

Tags: web-services, http, protractor, cucumber

I am testing a system which is running in an OSGI driven architecture. There is an interactive angular2-UI. There are also some peripheral hardware elements such as a light sensor attached. Signals from light sensor will be handled and will result in changes on UI (loading new screens etc.).

I use protractor and cucumber. All functionalities which are not related to hardware events can be easily tested. In order to simulate a the light-sensor-signal, and conclusively in order to test the new elements on the UI-screen, I have defined a webservice as an OSGI bundle, which is able to trigger appropriate backend behaviour. Via GET I ask the service to send a light-event on the bus. Then I wait for the system engine to receive that light-event, to handle it and to send screen-changes to all attached clients.

I defined this module to communicate with the service:

```
var http = require('http');

var Communication = function () {

this.activateProximity = function () {

    var deferred = protractor.promise.defer();

    var callback = function() {
        deferred.fulfill();
        browser.logger.info('proximity-request- promise fullfilled!...');
    };

    var options = {
            hostname: 'localhost',
            port: '12345',
            path: '/test/proximity/activate',
            method: 'GET',            
    };

    var req = http.request(options, callback);
    req.end();
    return deferred.promise;
};

};

module.exports = Communication;
```

And I call the method in my Testscript:

```
    this.Given(/^I am on the homescreen$/, function () {
    homeScreenPageObject.getToHome();
    browser.logger.info("we got the url...");       
 });

this.When(/^the proximity is activated$/, function(){
    browser.logger.info("Ask backend to activate proximity...");
    communication.activateProximity().then(function(){
        browser.sleep(5000); 
    });
});


this.Then(/^the distance-element is displayed$/, function(){ 
    homeScreenPageObject.isShowingDistanceElement(minValue);
});
```

Where the homeScreenPageobject is like:

```
var HomeScreenPageObject = function() {

  this.distanceElement = element(by.id('distance-element'));
  ...

  this.getToHome = function() {
     browser.ignoreSynchronisation = false;
    return browser.get("http://localhost:12345/index.html#/homescreen");
  };

  this.isShowingDistanceElement = function(minvalue){
    var value =minvalue;
    this.distanceElement.isDisplayed().then( function(displayed) {          
        if (displayed) {
            ...
        } 
        else {
             ...
        }
    } , function(err) {  browser.logger.info("Error: "+ err.message); 
    });
}
...


}
```

The request is well sent and backend does his work and sends new screen-elements to all clients. Clients which was not started via webdriver show the "distance-element". But the browser which was opened via webdriver does not get updated. Consequently my "Then-function" fails since the "distance-element" is not found on the page. 
I used a browser.sleep() after request was finished but still nothing updated.

Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: Can you provide more details on how the service is actually invoked by clients? What do you mean by backend does the work and sends new screen-elements to all clients? Based on above code, it does not look like browser opened by web driver is anyway connected to service call. The GET call is made separately. I don't see any interaction.

Comment: @ Surya, I have updated the description of my question. I hope it is clear now.

Comment: Thank you for the update. I feel instead of browser.sleep(5000) you should try something like  browser.wait(homeScreenPageObject.isShowingDistanceElement(minValue), 5000);              I feel the distance element check is more appropriate when done after proximity is activated.

Comment: @Surya: it did not help.  And I have to mention that after sending the request via communication module, none of the elements on the page are foundable by element(by.id('someId)) though they were before sending the request.